# PHP preg_match returns two matches instead of one

Tags: php, preg-match

I have this string: `ATL.556808.UMO20.02` and I want to get only `UMO20.02`.

Here is my `preg_match`:

```
$e = preg_match('"\.[^\.]+\.(.*?)$"si', $t, $m);
```

But this code return two matches instead of one. I got:

```
array(2) {  
 [0]=>   string(16) ".556808.UMO20.02"  
 [1]=>   string(8) "UMO20.02" 
}
```

But I want to get one match:

```
array(1) { 
 [0]=>   string(8) "UMO20.02" 
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: In your case `$m[0]` will be the match to the full pattern `"\.[^\.]+\.(.*?)$"` and `$m[1]` will be the first capture group `(.*?)`.  If you had more capture groups then you would have an `$m[2]` for the second etc...  So using your existing code just always use `$m[1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use the `s` and `i` flags as there are no specific cases for upper or lowercase chars, and the dot does not have to match a newline in the example data.

You can use

```
\.[^.]+\.\K.+$
```

- `\.` Match `.`
- `[^.]+\.` Match 1+ times any char except a `.`
- `\K` Forget what is matched
- `.+` Match any char 1+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nbF6Dv/1)

Example code

```
$re = '/\.[^.]+\.\K.+$/';
$str = 'ATL.556808.UMO20.02';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => UMO20.02
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `\.[^\.]+\.(.*?)$` regex matches a `.`, then any one or more chars other than a dot, then a dot, and then any zero or more chars as few as possible (*but as many as necessary to complete a match*) up to the end of string. The `.*?` must be *tempered* to match any chars but dots.

To remove all up to and including the second dot, you can use

```php
$t = 'ATL.556808.UMO20.02';
echo preg_replace('~^(?:[^.]+\.){2}~', '', $t);
// => UMO20.02
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/5qc5a). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zln6e3/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^.]+\.){2}` - two occurrences of any one or more chars other than a `.` and then a `.` char

Comment: your solution work on this example, but I need a regex which will be able to get everyting after second dot. In this example, your code works fine, but when I change string for: `CRA.556808.UMO2002A`, your code return `556808.UMO2002A` instead of: `UMO2002A`. I need a universal solution - which getting everyting after second dot.

Comment: @Pavvcio See updated answer, `preg_replace('~^(?:[^.]+\.){2}~', '', $t);`